# Make google drive access token dynamic in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, google-drive-api, access-token

I am facing an issue while making Google Drive API's access token dynamic in Python. I am getting issue

> "error": "unsupported_grant_type",\n  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "

Here is my API code in Python:

```
import requests

data = {
  'client_id': '*****',
  'client_secret': '*****',
  'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
  'access_type': 'offline',
  'redirect_uri': 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground',
  'code': '*****'

   }

  response = requests.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data=data)
  print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Try to enter this site: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and check your parameters

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I have visited the site but there also the grant_type is authorization_code. let me know if any other parameter i need to check.

Comment: Why not follow the [google drive python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) which uses the Google apis python client library.   Why are you doing this manually?  YOu cant use Oauth2 playground as your redirect uri anyway your code wont get the response googles servers will.

Comment: using this sample code, i am getting redirect_uri_mismatch error. what can be the reason for that? any idea?

Comment: Can you confirm the `redirect uri` is correct? Moreover are you able to replicate the request using the OAuth playground mentioned above? @GautamBothra

Comment: @ale13 While using Oauth playground manually, using the link:- https://help.talend.com/reader/Ovc10QFckCdvYbzxTECexA/EoAKa_oFqZFXH0aE0wNbHQ  I am able to fetch the token but while using the above code mentioned in the question using python i am getting unsupported or invalid grant type error. And using google drive python quickstart link mentioned by DalmTo , I am getting redirect_uri_mismatch error. I am unable to find what i am missing in both things.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Can you provide more details about what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ale13, I just want to make the token dynamic. So that i don't have to refresh token each time manually.

Comment: Which documentation are you following?